# Decompose a number in its prime factors

Tags: c++, recursion

I have this recursive function that decompose a number in its prime factors, and show the result standard output for example

```
descompon(2, 10);
```

Output

```
2 = 2
3 = 3
4 = 2^2
5 = 5
6 = 2 * 3
7 = 7
8 = 2^3
9 = 3^2
10 = 2 * 5
```

The code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int comprobar_primo( int* num, int e )
{
    if (*num%e == 0)
    {
        *num /= e;
        return 1 + comprobar_primo(num, e);
    }
    return 0;
}
std::string factor_primo(int a, int b, std::stringstream& fact)
{
    unsigned exp = comprobar_primo(&a, b);
    if (exp >= 1)
    {
        fact << b;
        if (exp > 1) fact << '^' << exp;
        if (a != 1) fact << " * ";
    }
    if (a > 1) factor_primo(a, b + 1, fact);
    return fact.str();
}
void descompon(int a, int b, int ver)
{
    std::stringstream fact;
    //std::string result = factor_primo(a, 2, fact);
    if(ver)
        std::cout << a << " = " << factor_primo(a, 2, fact) << std::endl;
    if(a < b)
        descompon( a + 1, b, ver);
}
int main(void)
{
    descompon(2, 10000, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when reaches the 5922 the program remains frozen, showing:

```
Process returned -1073741819 <0xC0000005>
```

why this happens and how I can avoid?

Comment: Do you really need to store everything in a single string, rather than print it as you go? If you do need to store everything, you should allocate the string dynamically, since one likely cause of your crash is stack overflow.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: Why do you call `descompon` recursively? You can turn this tail recursion into a simple loop. Likely your problem is stack overflow from recursion.

Comment: @Lundin not necessarily, this would solve the problem?

Comment: @cheroky well yeah, it probably would. Right now you're guaranteed a call-stack depth of 9999 slots *minimum*. Toting along all the automatics along for the ride. Throw out the recursing line in `descompon`, and wrap the entire remaining body of `descompon` in a `while (a < b)` loop that increments `a` by one at its tail, then run it again.

Comment: @WhozCraig you could create a answer,

Comment: @Lundin I tried without saving the string, but the problem persists, I edited the code

Comment: @cheroky Well, looking at this more carefully, the stack overflow more likely comes from the recursion than the strings. In 99% of all cases, recursion is only good for making program slow and creating stack overflow. There's absolutely no reason why you need to use recursion in this case. You can try to change to heap allocation to see if stack overflow was indeed the issue. But if so, the core problem is the recursion. To properly get rid of the bug, you have to get rid of the recursion, which you should probably do anyway.

Comment: @Lundin how to do the heap allocation in this case, sorry is still am an apprentice

Comment: @Lundin has it: Refactor the functions `factor_primo` and `descompon` so that they use loops instead of recursion and the program runs even with a small stack.

Comment: @M Oehm You can publish the version with loops of the two please

Answer (score 0):

Both your `factor_primo` and `descompon` functions can potentially cause stack overflow. Its better to convert them into iterative version. Modified code is given below:

```
// no need to pass b as argument since we start from b=2 and increment b by 1
std::string factor_primo(int a, std::stringstream& fact)  
{
    for(int b=2; a>1; b++)
    {
        if(a%b==0)
        {
            unsigned exp=comprobar_primo(&a, b);
            if(exp >= 1)
            {
                fact << b;
                if(exp > 1) fact << '^' << exp;
                if(a != 1) fact << " * ";
            }
        }
    }
    return fact.str();
}
void descompon(int a, int b, int ver)
{
    if(ver)
    {
        for(int i=a; i<=b; i++) {
            std::stringstream fact;
            std::cout << i << " = " << factor_primo(i, fact) << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    descompon(2, 10000, 1);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```